# laravel - adding message to newly registered validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel

after the server I am on doesn't have FILE_INFO enabled, I needed a quick way to validate a word document.

```
Validator::register( 'word', function( $attribute, $value, $parameters )
{

    $valid_type = array(
        'application/msword',
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
    );

    $valid_extentions = array(
        'doc',
        'docx'
    );

    if( ! is_array( $value ) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    if( ! isset( $value['type'] ) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    if( ! in_array( strtolower( $value['type'] ), $valid_type ) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    if( ! in_array( strtolower( substr( strrchr( $value['name'], '.' ) , 1 ) ), $valid_extentions ) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;

});
```

I know it's not bullet proof but will do for now (add suggestions if you have any) but how do I add a message for this as currently it returns

```
validation.word
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a new validation rule and message.

A custom rule looks like this:

```
$rules = array(
    'input_file' => 'required|word',
);
```

The messages looks like this:

```
$messages = array(
    'word' => 'The document must be .doc!',
);
```

And finally you have to call your validator with the rules and messages:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::get(), $rules, $messages);
```

Checkout the official documentation [Custom Validation](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Comment: This is great! Do you know where I need to place the *Custom Validation Rule* in order to be global? I use Validator::extend()

Answer (score 3):

To make the **message** global add it to */app/lang/en/validation.php* in the main array after the "url" like so

```php
<?php
return array(
    //...
    "url"              => "The :attribute format is invalid.",
    "word"             => "The document must be a Microsoft Word-file.",
//..
```

To make the **custom validation rule** global use the */app/validators.php* and add something like the following:

```php
<?php

class CustomValidator extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator
{
    //validate foo_bar
    public function validateFooBar($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        return ($value == 'foobar');
    }
}

Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
{
    return new CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
});
```